# How can I write vigenere cryptanalysis of persian text?

Tags: persian, vigenere, cryptanalysis

How can I write Vigenere cryptanalysis for persian language?
Is there any sample source code for persian?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a Persian-language version of Vignere cryptanalysis.

You could try one of the solutions [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher/Cryptanalysis) and adapt the alphabet used to the persian alphabet. (You'll need persian-language letter usage statistics, it won't work with english ones.) I recommend the python but that's just personal taste.

Comment: I have persian-language letter usage statistics. how can I adapt for example this code:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher/Cryptanalysis#Python
to work in persian?

Comment: Change the input text, the target_freqs, and tweak the calls to `ord(A)` and `uppercase`. You might be able to do the last one by setting your python locale. Is your Persian in unicode or ASCII?

Comment: in unicode.
I have only this frequencies:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=3960560711&photo_id=9035287093#9035287093
and the encrypt text. how can I tweak the calls to ord(A) and uppercase?

Comment: `ord(A)` should probably be changed to `ord(ـا)` or whatever. The locale can be set using [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) A complete rewrite of this code is outside the scope of a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: it said Key: Text is too short to analyze
Text: it doesn't return decode text

Comment: @bigOTHER see my above comment, can you help me?