# AttributeError in python3

Tags: python, attributeerror

I want to adapt [this code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher/Cryptanalysis#Python) to work in persian text.

I changed it as can be seen in the code bellow in which the `english_frequency` and `ordA` are changed. But, it has an error with `uppercase` in line:

```
cleaned = [ord(c) for c in input.upper() if c.isupper()].
```

Can you help me to adapt it?

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from operator import itemgetter

def vigenere_decrypt(target_freqs, input):
nchars = len(ascii_uppercase)
ordA = ord('ا')
sorted_targets = sorted(target_freqs)

def frequency(input):
    result = [[c, 0.0] for c in ascii_uppercase]
    for c in input:
        result[c - ordA][1] += 1
    return result

def correlation(input):
    result = 0.0
    freq = frequency(input)
    freq.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

    for i, f in enumerate(freq):
        result += f[1] * sorted_targets[i]
    return result

cleaned = [ord(c) for c in input.upper() if c.isupper()]
best_len = 0
best_corr = -100.0

# Assume that if there are less than 20 characters
# per column, the key's too long to guess
for i in xrange(2, len(cleaned) // 20):
    pieces = [[] for _ in xrange(i)]
    for j, c in enumerate(cleaned):
        pieces[j % i].append(c)

    # The correlation seems to increase for smaller
    # pieces/longer keys, so weigh against them a little
    corr = -0.5 * i + sum(correlation(p) for p in pieces)

    if corr > best_corr:
        best_len = i
        best_corr = corr

if best_len == 0:
    return ("Text is too short to analyze", "")

pieces = [[] for _ in xrange(best_len)]
for i, c in enumerate(cleaned):
    pieces[i % best_len].append(c)

freqs = [frequency(p) for p in pieces]

key = ""
for fr in freqs:
    fr.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

    m = 0
    max_corr = 0.0
    for j in xrange(nchars):
        corr = 0.0
        c = ordA + j
        for frc in fr:
            d = (ord(frc[0]) - c + nchars) % nchars
            corr += frc[1] * target_freqs[d]

        if corr > max_corr:
            m = j
            max_corr = corr

    key += chr(m + ordA)

r = (chr((c - ord(key[i % best_len]) + nchars) % nchars + ordA)
     for i, c in enumerate(cleaned))
return (key, "".join(r))


def main():
encoded = "بفعاع پهيتش غعهدد ذصلدي هزفضر کنهرظ ضذکاح يصتمد فهزگع " 
english_frequences = [
    14, 4.2, 0.7, 5.2, 0.1, 1.2, 0.4,
    1, 1.4, 7.5, 0.1, 8.5, 2.1, 0.1,
    3.3, 2.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 1.5,
    0.2, 1.6, 1.2, 3, 1.7, 2.7, 5.7, 7.1, 6, 5.7, 9.1]

(key, decoded) = vigenere_decrypt(english_frequences, encoded)
print ("Key:", key)
print ("\nText:", decoded)

main()
```

Comment: Post the exact error message

Comment: `input.upper()` needs to be changed to `input().upper()`.

Comment: when I use that it has this error:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: what error messsage did you get?

Comment: it has has several errors for example:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 89, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 85, in main
(key, decoded) = vigenere_decrypt(english_frequences, encoded)
File "main.py", line 30, in vigenere_decrypt 
for i in xrange(2, len(cleaned) // 20):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: @viol this is a python2 code, you can;t run it using python3 unless you rewrite differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly a python 2 code, and you are running it using a python 3 interpreter.

Use Python 2.

Also, compared to [the original](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher/Cryptanalysis#Python), you ruined the indentation of many blocks.

Comment: thanks, when I run it in python2 it has SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file main.py on line 6, but no encoding declared.

Comment: @viol add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as first line, and please consider to mark answer as accepted

Comment: when I do that it has this error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 91, in <module> main() File "main.py", line 87, in main (key, decoded) = vigenere_decrypt(english_frequences, encoded) File "main.py", line 8, in vigenere_decrypt ordA = ord('ا') TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Comment: @viol `ord()` accepts only one character, i suggest ask this a new independent question and put only code relevant to it. ping me if you want

Comment: 'ا' also is one character.

Comment: Farisi characters are 2 bytes, you should use u"ا"

Comment: it said Key: Text is too short to analyze Text: it doesn't return decode text. Is it any thing wrong with uppercase when use persian?

Comment: Dont' think so, I suggest you to ask it as new independent question

Comment: I asked this before in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795192/how-can-i-write-vigenere-cryptanalysis-of-persian-text/34795298?noredirect=1#comment57335256_34795298

Comment: @viol that's a different question,  its the general one.

Comment: ok, I made another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829728/python-uppercase-and-ascii-in-persian-text?noredirect=1#comment57401510_34829728